# Overriding Inline css of wordpress template

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet, inline, element

I want to override the style padding-top:100px to padding-top:0px. How can i override the inline style inside wordpress template?

```
<!-- Sidebar With Content Section-->
    <div class="with-sidebar-wrapper">
  <section id="content-section-1" >
  <div class="gdlr-full-size-wrapper gdlr-show-all"  style="padding-top: 100px; padding-bottom: 0px;  background-color: #ffffff; "  ><div class="gdlr-master-slider-item gdlr-slider-item gdlr-item"  style="margin-bottom: 0px;"  >
    <!-- MasterSlider -->
```

I already tried the below code in style.css but its not working!

```
.gdlr-full-size-wrapper .gdlr-show-all{
padding-top:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To select this perticular `<div>` you to write your `CSS` like:

```
 .gdlr-full-size-wrapper.gdlr-show-all {

 } /*without space between*/
```

you're using

```
 .gdlr-full-size-wrapper .gdlr-show-all {

 }
```

viz selecting

```
<div class="gdlr-full-size-wrapper">
   <div class="gdlr-show-all"></div>
</div>
```

Also if you're willing to override `inline CSS` only then you can use `[style]` selector also.

As:

```
<div class="someClass" style="font-size:10px; "></div>
```

So we can write `CSS` like:

```
.someClass[style] { font-size:14px !important}
```

what's trick here is this `CSS` only works when `someClass` has `inline CSS` for `font`.

Comment: Can anyone explain how inline styles are created in wordpress and how can I modify directly without using the above method. Is it possible?

Comment: Where to add that JS statement, i mean in which php file?  (I'm new to wordpress)

Comment: @DeebashVFX I don't know WP too, but you must put that to `.js` file

Answer (score 0):

Use following code it will work for both cases if you have one or both classes on div tag.

```
.gdlr-full-size-wrapper.gdlr-show-all, .gdlr-full-size-wrapper .gdlr-show-all
{
 padding-top:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Justinas explains it well and that should work perfectly, I have applied the same to custom CSS of a WordPress theme and has worked for me. The CSS I had trouble changing were inline a div.